# Ansible extract values from stdout_lines to use in subsequent loop

Tags: ansible, iso, cisco

I am trying to write a role to remove all helper addresses for a Cisco Router interface. There can be one or more helper addresses returned in stdout_lines. I use filters to remove labels and extra scapes from the lines and put the results into an array to use in the subsequent command loop. I seem to get the correct info but using the value fails.
Here is my role:

```yaml
---
- name: read helpers
  register: helper_facts
  ios_command:
     commands:
        - show ip interface {{ interface }} | section Helper

- set_fact:
    helper_addr: []

- set_fact:
    helper_addr: "{{ helper_addr }}  + [ '{{ item | regex_replace ('Helper address.* ','') | trim  }}' ]"
  with_items: "{{ helper_facts.stdout_lines }}"

- name: remove helpers
  ios_command:
     commands:
        - no ip helper-address {{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ helper_addr }}"
```

**Here is a snip of the output with the error I get:**

````
ok: [ONTMDFRTR01] => (item=                       172.16.0.22) => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "helper_addr": [
            "192.1.0.1",
            "172.16.0.22"
        ]
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "                       172.16.0.22"
}

TASK [remove_helpers : remove helpers] **********************************************************************************
task path: /home/msimon/USPS/roles/remove_helpers/tasks/main.yml:15
Monday 03 May 2021  16:44:23 -0400 (0:00:00.704)       0:00:05.874 ************
<10.32.178.252> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<10.32.178.252> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-23291P_KVGE `"&& mkdir "1-258083848203070 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1620074664.59-23371-258083848203070="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-232
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/network/ios/ios_command.py
<10.32.178.252> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-23291P_KVGE/tmpuSDML5 TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-23291P_KVG
<10.32.178.252> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-23291P_KVGE/ansible-tmp-1620074664.59-23371-24.59-23371-258083848203070/AnsiballZ_ios_command.py && sleep 0'
<10.32.178.252> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-23291P_KVGE/ansible-tmp-1620074664.59-2
<10.32.178.252> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-23291P_KVGE/ansible-tmp-1620074664.59-23371-25
The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_ios_command_payload_IFZQ7s/ansible_ios_command_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/network/ios/ios.py",
    return connection.run_commands(commands=commands, check_rc=check_rc)
  File "/tmp/ansible_ios_command_payload_IFZQ7s/ansible_ios_command_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/connection.py", line
    raise ConnectionError(to_text(msg, errors='surrogate_then_replace'), code=code)
failed: [ONTMDFRTR01] (item=192.1.0.1) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "auth_pass": null,
            "authorize": null,
            "commands": [
                "no ip helper-address 192.1.0.1"
            ],
            "host": null,
            "interval": 1,
            "match": "all",
            "password": null,
            "port": null,
            "provider": null,
            "retries": 10,
            "ssh_keyfile": null,
            "timeout": null,
            "username": null,
            "wait_for": null
        }
    },
    "item": "192.1.0.1",
    "msg": "no ip helper-address 192.1.0.1\r\nno ip helper-address 192.1.0.1\r\n   ^\r\n% Invalid input detected at '^' m
}```
````

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to SO. Please don't truncate error messages, as the rest of it may be the key piece of information required to help you. I don't have an IOS device in order to know, but if you type that exact command outside of ansible, does it do what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for jogging my brain. I cut this from a larger playbook and left out the commands to setup the interface ("config t" , "int GigabitEthernet0/0/0"). My role is working now as expected. Thanks, I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to mdaniel's comment I found the answer. I cut this from a larger playbook and left out the commands to setup the interface ("config t" , "int GigabitEthernet0/0/0") needed before the no helper_addres command. My role is now working  as expected. Thanks, I hope this helps someone else.